# Unitary transformations for angular momentum operators (reminder)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

In "rotating" the angular momentum components, one can get relations such as

$$
e^{-i\mu L_y}L_x e^{i\mu L_y} = L_x\cos{(\mu)} + L_z \sin{(\mu)}.
$$

Can anyone remind me of the relations for $e^{-i\mu L_z}L_x e^{i\mu L_z}$ and $e^{-i\mu L_z}L_y e^{i\mu L_<}$, or in general

$$
e^{-i\mu L_i}L_j e^{i\mu L_i} = \;?
$$

[For example in p301 of [this reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527408797) one can find some of these relations, but not all of them.]

**EDIT:**

In case anyone is interested, the answer for two generic (non-commuting) operators $A$ and $B$ is

$$
e^ABe^{-A} = A + [A,B] + \frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]] + \frac{1}{3!}[A,[A,[A,B]]]+\dots
$$

so with this relation, in particular $e^{-i\mu L_i}L_j e^{i\mu L_i}$ follows.

Comment: why not rederive by yourself? It's not that hard or do you expect us to do the work for you?... and BTW it's $\cos(\mu)$ and $\sin(\mu)$, not $2\mu$.

Comment: I've deleted an impolite comment. Be kind and assume good faith, folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is homework so I'll just give a hint. Basically your formula for
$$\exp(i \mu L_y) L_x \exp(-i \mu L_y)$$
is enough to determine all others. Simply use that if $U$ is a rotation matrix, then
$$U \exp(i \mu L_y) L_x \exp(-i \mu L_y) U^\dagger = U \exp(i \mu L_y) U^\dagger \cdot U L_x U^\dagger \cdot U \exp(-i \mu L_y) U^\dagger$$
and note that
$$U \exp(i \mu L_y) U^\dagger = \exp(i \mu U L_y U^\dagger).$$
For suitable choices of $U$, you can change $(L_x, L_y)$ into any of the pairs $(L_i,L_j)$.

Comment: No, it's not homework.

Comment: @user2820579 it is certainly homework-like.

Comment: Yes, but it is not. Look,  if you want the explanation I was looking for a kind of Adjoint action as stated in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). Actually I think this is the answer for the more general expression that I wrote.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I found the general expression and it does come as a formula in some books of Quantum Optics.